# how do i disable certain elements of a form using a radio button input?

Tags: javascript, forms

here is the fiddle page:
http://jsfiddle.net/hgcTb/10/

in the form there is a radio button with id = "extra"

i was hoping to do this:
when user clicks that radio button all other inputs are disabled, the only inputs that would be enabled is the radio buttons and the submit/reset buttons, and when user click reset the form should reset to the original form, maybe using javascript?

please give some pointers or samples

EDIT: ive added a function to disable each element but it is giving me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use javascript to do so.

Add an onclick event to your radio button that disables the other HTML elements. For example:

Here's your radio button:
`<input type="radio" name="choice" value="consume" onclick="disableItems(this)" />`

Here's your script:

```
function disableItems(obj) {

 var el = document.getElementById('<your HTML element's ID>');
 el.disabled = true;

 // do this for other HTML elements in your form
}
```

Regarding Reset, you can attach a similar onclick handler for the RESET button, that enables the controls back (using `el.disabled=false`).

These are just snippets to get you started, and give you an idea of how to proceed (no spoon-feeding for the exact solution). There may be more code involved based on your form's logic.

Comment: so i would have to do e#.disabled = true; for every element that i want to disable?

Comment: and what about the reset button? should i also attached a onclick to maybe set e#.disabled = false; for every element?

Comment: I just edited my response for that part of the question (which I missed earlier).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hgcTb/10/ for some reason it keep saying my function is not defined... function dis()

Comment: I'm not familiar with Fiddle, but I pasted the JS code within the HTML above (within the <script> tag) and it works like a charm! check it out.   From the page source it seems the JS code that you add in the Javascript pane does not get added as a <script>, but a <div>.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S2SxN/4/ hi here is another version im using jquery it works in jsfiddle but for some reason when i transfer this to an actual html file it does nothing, no errors =/